# Python: 'inf is inf', but '-inf is not -inf'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinity

Python 3.7

While writing the search code for the maximum, I encountered a strange behavior of negative infinity.
**Can somebody explain why this behavior?**

```py
>>> inf = float('inf')
>>> inf is inf
True
>>> (-inf) is (-inf)
False
```

And I've already realized it's better to use `==` for comparison, but I'm interested in the answer to the question above.

Comment: Hm, seems like — when negation, it creates a different object rather than mutating the existing. @chepner answered it already.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`inf` is a variable, bound to a specific object. Any object `is` itself, so `inf is inf`.

`-inf` is an expression. It does math, and produces an object with value floating-point negative infinity. Python makes no promises about whether this will be the same object as any other object with that value. In your case, the two evaluations of `-inf` happened to produce different objects.

Again, there are **no promises** about what `-inf is -inf` will produce. The current CPython implementation happens to consistently produce False. PyPy's primitive handling [produces True](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#object-identity-of-primitive-values-is-and-id). A different Python version or implementation might inconsistently produce True or False based on current memory pressure, or whether you ran this as a script or interactively, or any other factor. CPython itself already has cases where object identity is different in a script or interactively; for example, this:

```
x = 1000
y = 1000
print(x is y)
```

prints different things in the current CPython implementation depending on whether you run it interactively.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks. 
It was also because of the bad names (`inf` number and `inf` variable). In that case, it's better to keep the negative infinity separate:
```python
inf = float('inf'); ninf = -inf; ninf is ninf
```

Comment: @ДаниилКонягин: Just **don't use `is` for floats**. It is the wrong comparison.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out, too.

Answer (score 7):

`-inf` is an operation that produces a new `float` object, and you use it twice in the same expression. Two distinct objects are produced, because a Python implementation is not required to notice that both subexpressions could return a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add one point: in Python, when we use `id()` function, `is` operator, `==` operator, etc, the real target we're working with is **value**, not **variable**.

`a is b` equals to `id(a) == id(b)`.

In your code, `inf = float('inf')` will produce a value named `inf`.

`inf` is also an expression, which will be evaluated to a value.

`inf is inf` will be `True`, because the evaluated values of two expressions are same one, in fact.

In Python, focusing on values is better and easier.

For example, in CPython implementation:

```py
a = 1
b = 1
a is b # will be true

a = 10000
b = 10000
a is b # will be false

a = '10000'
b = '10000'
a is b # will be true
```

If we focus on variable, such thing is weird. If we focus on values, and if I tell you that CPython implementation has cache pool, which is used for small int and some literal str value, such thing is simple again:

Because of cache pool, small int `1` is cached, str `'10000'` is cached too, but big int `10000` is not cached so it will be created two times.

Try to focus on values.